# XMPP Muc Queries

Tags: xmpp, smack, muc

I am using session resumption with large resumption time - 24 hours - http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html . I have a doubt about muc, if I am in group and my client rejoin, do I need to leave and rejoin the group to get the new messages. For non muc stanzas, they are kept in offline storage and delivered as soon as I reconnect. But I am not sure about muc.

If it is not so the case I don't think there is any advantage of being online - except to fetch occupants list. Again I am not sure if I will get occupant joined event if my client was offline.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reconnect for getting messages from a room,but one thing once you goes to offline then you automatically kicked out from MUC room ,so you need to reconnect to room for getting offline messages when you are come to online.